# Contar e acessar checkbox marcados

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

Preciso contar os checkbox marcados que estão em um panel e estão na horizontal. É Windows form, C#. Não consegui formatar um listbox para a horizontal, então está em um panel mesmo. Mas gostaria de contá-los e acessá-los com um laço. tentei concatenar os nomes que estão em sequência, tentei via código, também sem sucesso. Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O facto dos *ChckBox's* estarem num *Painel* irá facilitar a sua contagem em um laço.
O objecto *Painel* mantém uma lista dos objectos do tipo *Control* que estão no "seu interior" na propriedade *Controls*.
Basta então percorrer essa lista e, quando se encontra um *CheckBox*, verificar se está *checked* e contá-los.

```
private int getCheckedCount()
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (Control control in panel1.Controls)
    {
        if (control is CheckBox) 
        {
            if(control.Checked) count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```